# How to find top 10 between two columns in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I use the following in order to find the top 10 rows in that column.

```
df.nlargest(10, 'column_a')
```

Now, what if I have two different columns (columns_a and column_b) that I need to extract the top 10 values from?

Comment: It helps if there is a sample dataframe, with expected output. You can use a list of labels in nlargest: ``df.nlargest(10, ['column_a', 'column_b'])``

Answer (score 1):

you can use [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) function

```
df.sort_values(by=["columns_a","column_b"],ascending=[False,False])
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but it sorts only based on the first column in the list (column_a)

Comment: I mean, it first sorts based on the column_a, and then it sorts based on the column_b. What I need is to find the top 10 in combination of both columns. For example the highest value might be in column_a, and then the second highest value might be in column_b

Comment: @hmd could you give sample dataset and expected output